# Node Cluster - replace worker.js file with code

Tags: node.js, worker

The below example is from Node Documentation :

```
import cluster from 'cluster';

cluster.setupPrimary({
  exec: 'worker.js',
  args: ['--use', 'https'],
  silent: true
});
cluster.fork(); // https worker
cluster.setupPrimary({
  exec: 'worker.js',
  args: ['--use', 'http']
});
cluster.fork(); // http worker
```

When packaging the application into a redistributable binary, `exec: 'worker.js'` is problematic the `worker.js` has to be packaged along with the exe. Is there a way to tell `cluster` to look at a piece of code instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course. That's the usual behavior of cluster when not using the new `.setupPrimary` method. You can use the `env` argument of `.fork()` to pass arguments:

```js
import cluster from 'cluster';

if (cluster.isPrimary) {
  cluster.fork({use: 'https'});
  cluster.fork({use: 'http'});
} else {
  if (process.env.use && process.env.use == 'https') {
    // code for https worker
  } else if (process.env.use && process.env.use == 'http') {
    // code for http worker
  } else {
    console.log("missing 'use' environment variable in worker");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This guided me in the right direction.